# How to start ListActivity from intent?

Tags: android

I have a class `ListNotes` which extends a  `ListActivity` and in another class I have an intent which reffers to a `ListNotes` class. The problem is that I get an error "Sorry! The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". When I change a `ListActivity` to just an `Activity`, the error disappears. But I really need to extend a `ListActivity`, as I have a `ListView` in it. Can I modify this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyNotepad.this, ListNotes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

to make it work? Maybe there is sth like `startListActivity(intent);` ?

Comment: No there is no such method. Can you please show me the stack trace? That may really help.

Comment: I surrounded my "Intent code" with try-catch, but stacktrace does not show anything. Rather I forgot how to use it is not printed.

Comment: Whenever Android show that warning message, it sure generates some exception. First you should check @kgiannakakis answer. That may be the issue.

Comment: are u sure your listactivity has been added to the manifest?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have added a ListView in the layout:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent">
```

The `@android:id/list` id is important for being able to use a ListActivity.

Comment: How to retrieve this id in our android program? I tried using listView l1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list) but it says list cannot be resolved or is not a field.It doesnt show error if i give android:id=@+id/mylist in my xml file but in this case i get force close error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `ListNotes` declared as an activity in your Manifest file?

Put this in between the `application` tags:

```
<activity
    android:name="ListNotes" />
```

Also, an error log from `LogCat` would help.

Edit:
The layout used in your `ListNotes` activity must contain a `ListView` with id `@android:id/list`, like the kgiannakakis mentioned.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't work. LogCat does not show any errors.

Comment: surely logcat will show something on a "forced close" message!